# Ext JS 5.1 Sencha CMD adding external css file

Tags: extjs5, sencha-cmd

I am creating an Ext JS application using sencha cmd V5.1. I am trying to load external css file, but it is not working.

My external css file location:

```
resources/css/customStyle.css
```

In the app.json file I added the path to the external file.

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "bootstrap.css",
        "bootstrap": true
    }, { 
        "path": "resources/css/customStyle.css" 
    }
],
```

But when I am using the cls class defined in the "customStyle.css" in the application, it is not working.

Please help me how I can use the external css file using Sencha CMD.

Answer (score 0):

When you are including css files in app.json, you have to first run

```
sencha app refresh
```

and then

```
sencha app build development
```

After that sencha cmd will create bundled css files, which should also include your custom styles.

The bundled css files are usually located in

```
build/development/YOUR_APP/
```

If the bundled CSS files are not generated you could try running sencha cmd with --debug flag

```
sencha --debug app build development
```